# How to add widget specifically in subcategory Genesis Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, genesis

Basically i have these category hierarchy

- /service [parent][id -> 3]

  - posts
  - /service/type [sub] [id -> 11]

    - /service/type/outsourcing [sub]
  - /service/problem [sub] [id -> 12]

    - /service/type/outsourcing [sub]

I have a widget that supposedly just target /service/type and /service/problem but the problem is the widget also adds to posts under /service.

Here's the code to create widget that's in functions.php

```html
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'service-type-widget',
'name' => __( 'Service Type Page', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'For service page', 'childtheme' ),
) );
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'service_type_widget' );
function service_type_widget() {
    if ( in_category('3')) {
        genesis_widget_area( 'service-type-widget', array(
        'before' => '<div class="widget--service-type widget--service widget-area">',
        'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question needs to be asked in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using this is_subcategory() that @bainternet answered
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/equivalent-to-in-category-for-subcategories

```html
function is_subcategory($category = null) {
    if (is_category()) {
        if (null != $category){
            $cat = get_category($category);
        }else{
            $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
        }
        if ($cat->parent == 0 ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'service-type-widget',
'name' => __( 'Service Type Page', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'For service page', 'childtheme' ),
) );
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'service_type_widget' );
function service_type_widget() {
    if ( is_subcategory('11')) {
        $child_cats = get_categories('&child_of=3');
        genesis_widget_area( 'service-type-widget', array(
        'before' => '<div class="widget--service-type widget--service widget-area">',
        'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    }
}
```